How to add macOS Specific code in Kotlin Compose Multi Platform?
I want to write macOS specific code like bluetooth permission or other lower level code which is very specific to macOS which needs to be written in Objective C or Swift.
Creating KMM project from project wizard makes a project hierarchy as follows

commonMain
androidMain
desktopMain

How to create a macos main folder and edit the macos specific code? can i create a  macOS main package by myself or what correct configurations should i do in my gradle code ?
My current gradle file is as follows
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.composeMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.composeCompiler)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_11)
        }
    }
    
    jvm("desktop")
    macosArm64()
    applyDefaultHierarchyTemplate()

    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting
        
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.compose)
        }
        desktopMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.swing)
        }
        val jvmAndMacos by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain.get())
        }

        macosArm64Main.get().dependsOn(jvmAndMacos)
        jvmMain.get().dependsOn(jvmAndMacos)
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.shekhar.multiplatformapp"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.shekhar.multiplatformapp"
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.android.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

dependencies {
    debugImplementation(compose.uiTooling)
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "com.shekhar.multiplatformapp.MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "com.shekhar.multiplatformapp"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}


https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-discover-project.html#source-sets

@CommonsWare I did read this but they have mentioned nowhere how can i include macos specific folder

See the "Intermediate source sets" section and references to macosArm64 (for Apple Silicon Macs). See also the Tier 1 target list citing macosX64 and macosArm64, among others. A source set is configured in Gradle but also has an associated "specific folder" for source code tied to that source set.
